# I can't find a way to simulate a click/tap with WKWebView and Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, swift, mobile-safari, wkwebview

Im trying to simulate a mobile click/tap with swift/javascript. The click is on a  tag with no Id. I've tried .click(), .onclick() and .submit().

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('button').click();", completionHandler: { (value, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print("Unsuccessfull")
                print(error as Any)
            }
            else{
                print("Successfull")
            }
        })
```

Here is the html tag

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-greyscale join ng-binding" blocking="" data-functional-selector="join-button-username">Go</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a [0] or where ever the tag is to the code

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click()", completionHandler: nil)
```